# python continuously prompting for user input until a certain word is entered

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input, binary-search

My code is working for the first input, but now I want to re-prompt the user for their input and repeat the process until the user enters 'stop'. I have tried placing my code within another while loop, creating a different function definition and putting code within the existing if statements. 
here is my code so far:

```
def findInfo(myList, target):
    list.sort(myList)
    #print myList, target
    guesses = 0
    low = 0
    high = len(myList)-1
    mid = (high + low) / 2
    while high >= low:
        if target == myList[mid][0]:
            print "Here are your results:"
            print 'state:', myList[mid][0]
            print 'total number:', myList[mid][1]
            print '% passed:', myList[mid][2]
            print '% female students:', myList[mid][3]
            return True            
        elif target > myList[mid][0]:
            low = mid + 1
            guesses += 1
            print "guess", guesses
        elif target < myList[mid][0]:
            high = mid - 1
            guesses += 1
            print "guess", guesses
        mid = (high + low)/ 2
    print False, "no match found"
    return False
```

I'm just really confused about where to put the code to re-ask the user for input until a certain word in entered.

Comment: I know the code isn't indented after the function definition, but that just happened when I copied my code. It's not like that in my python workspace.

Comment: Where do you get the first input from?

Comment: Where are you taking input? I don't see you asking the user anything. Where is the initial prompt?

Comment: oh right, sorry. Right now, I have the user prompt in a different function.
def askForUserInput():
    print " "
    print "To find information on a specific state, enter the name of the state."
    userState = str(raw_input("Entry:"))
    return userState
"myList" also refrences a list-within-a-list from a different function

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [cmd](http://pymotw.com/2/cmd/) lib, something similar:

```
import cmd


class myApp(cmd.Cmd):

    def do_findInfo(self,target, myList = defaultList):
        list.sort(myList)
        #print myList, target
        guesses = 0
        low = 0
        high = len(myList)-1
        mid = (high + low) / 2
        while high >= low:
            if target == myList[mid][0]:
                print "Here are your results:"
                print 'state:', myList[mid][0]
                print 'total number:', myList[mid][1]
                print '% passed:', myList[mid][2]
                print '% female students:', myList[mid][3]
                return True            
            elif target > myList[mid][0]:
                low = mid + 1
                guesses += 1
                print "guess", guesses
            elif target < myList[mid][0]:
                high = mid - 1
                guesses += 1
                print "guess", guesses
            mid = (high + low)/ 2
        print False, "no match found"
        return False   

        def do_EOF(self, line):
            return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().cmdloop()
```

this will show you the commandline where you need to enter: "findInfo target"

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do sth. like this:

```
def term(s):
    return s in ['stop', 'exit', 'quit']

if __name__=='__main__':
    inp = ''
    while not term(inp):
        inp = raw_input('prompt: ')
        if not term(inp):
            try:
                i = int(inp)
                print(findInfo(myList, i))
            except ValueError as e:
                print('Invalid input: {}'.format(e.message))
```